# What is the equivalent of $scope.$apply(); in Angular Typescript?

Tags: angular

After changing the `.filteredData` property of a mat-table object, I need to somehow refresh the table and update its contents.....

I know you can achieve this via `$scope.$apply()`, but what about in Angular TS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are looking for [`ChangeDetectorRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)

Normally this is done by Angulars change detection which gets notified by its zone that change detection should happen.

```
export class FooComponent implements OnInit{
   constructor (private _services: Services, private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {
   this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```